# how to segment text/handwritten lines using horizontal profile projection?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have managed to get the horizontal profile projection of a handwritten image(the code of which in python is mentioned below). I wish to segment the individual lines and save them. I know this can be done using other methods but I wish to implement it by the horizontal profile projection that I have obtained. Point/Pixel of interest is the starting point from where the projection profile initiates or it is greater than zero till again the projection profile reaches to zero.
[Horizontal Profile Projection of handwritten image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuAFl.jpg) 
The peaks in the image depicts where it detects the text in the image, now I wish to segment and save those sections/individual lines of text of the original image.

```py
    def getHorizontalProjectionProfile(image):
      # Convert black spots to ones
      image[image == 0] = 1
      # Convert white spots to zeros
      image[image == 255] = 0
      horizontal_projection = np.sum(image, axis=1)
      return (horizontal_projection, image)
    #Calling the horizontal projection function
    horizontal_projection = getHorizontalProjectionProfile(binary.copy())

    m = np.max(horizontal_projection[0])
    w = 500
    result = np.zeros((horizontal_projection[0].shape[0],500))
    for row in range(image.shape[0]):
       cv2.line(result, (0,row), (int(horizontal_projection[0]   [row]*w/m),row), (255,255,255), 1)
       cv2.imshow('Result', result)
       cv2.waitKey()
```

So the *result* variable displays the image of the horizontal profile projection. Also the variable *binary.copy()* holds the binary image of the input handwritten image.
Kindly let me know if the post requires any further changes.

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language you are using and add the code that you have tried so far! What is your specific issue with this task? A must-read article for new SO members is [ask].

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am now editing it, having read the article you mentioned. Please be kind enough to let me know whether I still lack anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def getHorizontalProjectionProfile(image):
    # convert black spots to ones and others to zeros
    binary = np.where(image == 0, 1, 0)
    # add up rows
    horizontal_projection = np.sum(binary, axis=1)
    return horizontal_projection


# read image and get threshold
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, 0)

# call the horizontal projection function
horizontal_projection = getHorizontalProjectionProfile(thresh)

start_of_line = 0
count = 0

for row in range(len(horizontal_projection)):
    if horizontal_projection[row] == 0:
        if start_of_line > 0:
            count += 1
            print(f"Line {count} found from row {start_of_line} to {row}")
            start_of_line = 0
    else:
        if start_of_line == 0:
            start_of_line = row
```

Output something like:

```
Line 1 found from row 15 to 43
Line 2 found from row 109 to 143
Line 3 found from row 156 to 190
Line 4 found from row 203 to 237
...
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to save the segmented lines of text image, getting the loop construction so as to get the rows was what I wasn't able to figure out. Thanks a tonne!